# DateTime Function in Python 3 error

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, datetime

I have a csv file with a column called 'EntryDate', some of the fields have dates and some are empty in mysql I have a default that should be set as '0000-00-00 00:00:00', the dates in the csv file are formatted as dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS
so inmy pyhton script I've changed it to be the proper format using the datetime function
     `d = datetime.strptime(row['EntryDate'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

but I keep getting this error

```
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

I've searched for a solution and tried many different ways I'm still getting this error,
your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either test whether the field is empty first, or catch the exception and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
try:
    d = datetime.strptime(row['EntryDate'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
except ValueError:
    d = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Alternatively:

```
if row['EntryDate'].strip() == '':
    d = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
else:
    d = datetime.strptime(row['EntryDate'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Update to show one way to do this for multiple columns as per OP's comment:

```
columns = ['EntryDate', 'DateDeparture']
for column in columns:
    if row[column].strip() == '':
        d = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    else:
        d = datetime.strptime(row[column], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # Do something with d here as you'll overwrite it on next iteration of loop.
```

Comment: Thank you , the if statement worked well for me Could i ask is there anyway to use the same if statment on multiple date columns instead of just one? say row['DateEntry'], row['DateDeparture']?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show one possible way of extending this to use with multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate the help. Its working fine thank you